# Problems uploading file via FTP

Tags: php, file, ftp, upload

I am following the example exposed in the PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/ftp.examples-basic.php

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

What do you mean by $ destination_file and $ source_file?

I have little experience with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php):

> remote_file: The remote file path.
>
> local_file: The local file path.

In other words, `$destination_file` is the location and filename of where you want to write to the FTP server.  `$source_file` is the location and filename of the file you want to upload.

Also, I'd strongly recommend using something other than FTP whenever possible.  FTP has numerous security vulnerabilities, the worst of which is the fact that your username/password are not encrypted.  It also runs into challenges with NAT and some firewall software as its commands and data transfers use independent TCP connections.  Use SCP or something else.